Accent in Cell FPDF function causes mis-alignment of content
If have this FPDF code:
 $pdf->Cell(65 ,3, "Helene",1, 1, 'R');
 $pdf->Ln(2);
 $pdf->Cell(65 ,3, "Hélène",1, 1, 'R');

This gives two different results:

Why accents provoke this problem? There is a shift between "Helene" and "Hélène"m so that "Hélène" is not right-justified, but "Helene" is right-justified. Could this be a problem of font not being UTF-8 compatible?
<?php
// Appel de la librairie FPDF
require("fpdf/fpdf.php");
// Création de la class PDF
class PDF extends FPDF {
     function Header()
    {
    }   
}
// Activation de la classe
$pdf = new PDF('L', 'mm', array(85, 54)); 
$HeaderVisible=1;
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
$pdf->SetTextColor(128, 128, 128);   //couleur grise
$pdf->AddPage('L'); 
$pdf->Cell(65 ,3, "Hélène",1, 1, 'R');
$pdf->Ln(2);
$pdf->Cell(65 ,3, "Helene",1, 1, 'R');
$nom = 'test2.pdf';
exec ("rm test2.pdf");
// Envoi des en-têtes
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$nom.'"');
$pdf->Output($nom);
echo $nom;
?>  


Thanks for your answer : there's a shift between "Helene" and "Hélène" for this 2 lines . So when there's accents inside the text for the Cell fpdf function , the text is not right justified. With no accent, there's no problem of alignment.

I used to work with FPDF in the past, and when UTF-8 became popular I used fFPDF. Maybe it can help you as well? It's an easy drop-in replacement. However, I've long since switched to a library that can translate HTML to PDF. It's just easier to use, since we already know HTML. I happen to mainly use DomPDF. None of these libraries are perfect however.

@KJ Yes, that's true. If the code in the question isn't the actually code used for the PDF, which it clearly isn't, then the question cannot be answered. Regrettably you cannot upload a PDF to Stack Overflow.

the code is the result of the image

The code in the question is far from complete. For starters, $pdf is undefined. You might think all the other code is irrelevant, and doesn't cause your problem, but since you don't know what causes your problem you cannot know that.

code is added now

After editing your code, so it doesn't create a file, but just lets me view it, I got this result. I also had to change the PHP script file from UTF8 to ANSI. In other words, I cannot reproduce your problem. Note instead of using exec("rm test2.pdf"); you can use unlink().

Also note that $pdf->Output($nom); seems invalid. According to the documentation it needs to be $pdf->Output('F', $nom);. No idea how you go any output from that code?

@K J : thanks: work perfectly : no shift with accents.
Perfect

@KIKO tks for tips !

Simple solution  your call:
$pdf->Cell(65 ,3, "Helene",1, 1, 'R');
```

Change the 'R' to 'C'  for centered
or
Change the 'R' to  'L' for left.

